# It is so imprecise to create a technical term **tty name** in **w** command

Tags: tty, device-name

Abstract from man w.

The following entries are displayed for each user: login name, the tty name, 
the remote host, login time, idle time, JCPU, PCPU, and the command  line  of  their current process.

Simply to say ,TTY is terminal which is used to type text message.
But what **tty name** mean here in w command?

```
w
21:27:06 up 39 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.26, 0.20, 0.17
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
test  :0       :0               20:48   ?xdm?   5:12   0.08s /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE
```

There is no kind of terminal named **:0**.
some expert told that :0 = "local:display #0": X11 server, used for graphical login (e.g. gdm).

```
ps -el|grep -e lxsession -e "CMD"
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000  1609  1597  0  80   0 - 91715 -      ?        00:00:00 lxsession
```

The ? mark  in the output info of **ps**  means that process has no controlling terminal. A process with no controlling terminal is a deamon.

It is so imprecise to create a technical term **tty name** in **w**  command.

Comment: Try `ps -lC Xorg`

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -el|grep -e lxsession -e "CMD"
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S  1000  1609  1597  0  80   0 - 91715 -      ?        00:00:00 lxsession
```

The lxsession is a daemon which  has no controlling terminal,so can't yield info such as **ttynumber(from 1 till 7)** or **pts/number**.
**w** yield  **:0** ,meaning **local:display #0** ,to describe the fact on the hardware side.
It's my problem not developer's.